# unknow error occur in razorpay using nodejs

Tags: node.js, razorpay

When I attempt to call `instance.payments.createPayment({})`, a 400 Bad Request error occurs.
Code:

```
instance.payments.createPaymentJson({
      amount: 10000,
      currency: 'INR',
      email: 'gaurav.kumar@example.com',
      contact: '9123456780',
      customer_id: 'cust_MpINfSkdEvtdxb',
      order_id: 'order_NGrgEcmYJsfUyl',
      ip: '192.168.0.103',
      method: 'netbanking',
      bank: 'YESB',
      notes: {
        invoice_number: 'IRS1245',
        goods_description: 'Digital Lamp'
      }
    })
Error Message:
{
  statusCode: 400,
  error: {
    code: 'BAD_REQUEST_ERROR',
    description: 'The requested URL was not found on the server.',
    source: 'NA',
    step: 'NA',
    reason: 'NA',
    metadata: {}
  }
}
```

I want to resolve this Bad Request error.

Answer (score -1):

This issue might be caused by various factors. Here's a step-by-step guide to resolve the error:

1. **Check Razorpay API Documentation:**

   - Refer to the official [Razorpay API documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/) to ensure that you are using the correct API endpoint, method, and parameters for creating a payment.
2. **Verify API Endpoint and Method:**

   - Double-check the URL and method used in your API request. Ensure that you are using the appropriate endpoint for creating payments.
3. **Inspect Request Parameters:**

   - Review the request parameters you are passing in the `createPaymentJson` function. Ensure that all required parameters are included, and their values are correctly formatted.
4. **Check for Typos or Syntax Errors:**

   - Carefully inspect your code for any typos or syntax errors, especially in the payment creation request. Pay attention to commas, brackets, and quotes.
5. **Test with Minimal Parameters:**

   - Simplify your payment creation request by including only essential parameters (amount, currency, and order_id). Gradually add other parameters to identify the specific cause of the error.
6. **Update Razorpay Node.js SDK:**

   - Ensure that you are using the latest version of the Razorpay Node.js SDK. You can update it using npm with the following command:

     ```bash
     npm install razorpay@latest
     ```

By following these steps, you should be able to identify and resolve the 400 Bad Request error in your Razorpay Node.js integration.

Comment: kindly accept the answer, if it was informative